# How to place text at the start and another at end in the same alert tage in react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

for example in the below code the "created" span should come at the start of the alert tag and "sahood" should be at the end

```
<Alert> <span>Created by</span> <span>Sahood</span> </Alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display Alert as a flex-box and give it justify-content="space-between" with following bootstrap classes:

```
<Alert className="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span>Created by</span> <span>Sahood</span>
</Alert>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bogdan-yji42o